# Apache Nifi error: The specified template is not in a valid format

Tags: apache-nifi

I saved a flow in JSON format, but when tried to load it as a template the following error appeared:
*"The specified template is not in a valid format"*.

[image]

I noticed the other templates I uploaded were XML files and not JSON.
How can the template be saved as XML?

Answer (score 3):

Saving a flow is a different action than saving a template.
The template should be saved by "Create Template" action, which saves it in the templates list of the Nifi instance. 
Then, it is accessible via the Templates menu item:

[image]

Under the templates list, there is an option to download a selected template as an XML file. With that, the template can be exported and uploaded into another Nifi instance correctly without any error.